# What font is used in this logo for "MigrosMagazine"

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

I am trying to find the fonts used in the following Logo for the Swiss magazine "MigrosMagazine". I've been trying to use whatthefont.com, but haven't had much success.

[image: MigrosMagazine]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe "Linotype Ergo DemiBold":

[image]

Apart from http://www.whatthefont.com, you can also try with http://www.identifont.com

Comment: Close, but the curves at the ends of strokes (**G, S** and **c** in particular) are not as pronounced as the OP image. And the crossbar of **A** is at a different height.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that the title is specially drawn. The lower-case ***c*** looks like Arial Black, but not much else does.

I created this fairly easily:

[image: Avenir Next Bold]

[Avenir Next Bold](http://www.linotype.com/85996/AvenirNextProBold-product.html) at 110% width. Again, not perfect: the **R** has a straight leg and the x-height is smaller. Width and tracking could be played with, I think.